# I get the error when using get property value on Umbraco v8

Tags: umbraco8

I use Umbraco v8 and code is here

```
var home = Model.Root();
var results = home.Children.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsDocumentType("results"));
var resultSliders = (results?.GetProperty("resultSliders")?.GetValue() as IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>) ?? new List<IPublishedContent>();
```

error message is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

but the `results` content is not empty and `GetProperty("resultSliders").HasValue()` return is true so I have no idea why it is giving error `results?.GetProperty("resultSliders")?.GetValue()`. `resultSliders` Property is custom nested content data type

Comment: Which line is the error on? is `home` null? How about `home.Children`?

Comment: Contents not empty and error is `results?.GetProperty("resultSliders")?.GetValue()`

Comment: what could be the cause of the error? Custom nested content Type?

Comment: The "duplicate" question give some techniques to diagnose the problem. You might have to break up the statement into multiple statements and use the debugger to find out what is null.

Comment: If you have made changes to the data type or composition, you must edit it again on inherited doc types